# XSL Strip invalid characters from the value of an attribute

Tags: xslt

I have the following **anchor** `<a name="http://www.ctvnews.ca"/>`

Now this works but it's not valid because and `HTML` strict compliant. In this case the issue is that the character "/" is not allowed in the value of attribute "name".

Is it possible from the XSL style sheet to strip out the `http://` and just keep the `www.ctvnews.ca`?

EDIT:

If i normally grab data like this `<xsl:value-of select="Name"/>`

Would the correct implementation then be:

`<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(Name,'http://')"/>`

Because all this returns is an empty string for me :(

EDIT 2: I figured it out! Thank you. It's because i have https. Is there any way to do a regex here and say something like 'http?://'

Where the ? can represent 0 or 1 s being there?

**UPDATE**

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains(Name, 'https://')">
        <div style="font-size: 300%;">Site: <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(Name,'https://')"/></div>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <div style="font-size: 300%;">Site: <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(Name,'http://')"/></div>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

is my solution but a regex would be nicer for a one timer ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use substring-after to get the required output

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(/a/@name,'http://')"/>





<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <a>
<xsl:attribute name="name">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(/a/@name,'http://')"/>
       </xsl:attribute>
      </a>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i get an empty string back :(

Comment: Please check if your XML input contains and parent to <a name="http://www.ctvnews.ca"/>, in such case change the xpath accordingly or try using                                                                                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(//a/@name,'http://')"/>

Comment: Some are `http` and some are `https` so i use a xsl:choose :) unless there is a more elegant way to use a regex and solve this :)